# Can't get jqplot.DateAxisRenderer to work with hours

Tags: jqplot

I'm trying to plot the values over 24 hours. I'm working from [this](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/date-axes.php) example on the jqplot site. I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="javascript/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart1"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var line2=[['2008-06-30 8:00AM',4], ['2008-06-30 9:00AM',6.5], ['2008-06-30 10:00AM',5.7], ['2008-06-30 11:00AM',9], ['2008-06-30 12:00PM',8.2]];
  var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line2], {
      title:'Customized Date Axis',
      gridPadding:{right:35},
      axes:{
        xaxis:{
          renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
          tickOptions:{formatString:'%r'}
        }
      },
      series:[{lineWidth:4, markerOptions:{style:'square'}}]
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: which errors do you get when you open firebug?

Comment: Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString' -- Sorry, I'm still out of ideas.

Comment: seems like the line2 variable is causing some trouble because of its string format. maybe for giggles just try changing that to like number of some sort and see if it works

Comment: This plots: var line2=[['2008-06-30 8:00AM',4], ['2008-06-30 9:00AM',6.5], ['2008-06-30 10:00AM',5.7], ['2008-06-30 11:00AM',9], ['2008-10-30 12:00PM',8.2]];

but it's not right because the date on the end is 10 not 6.

This plots but all of the points are on the right side: 
  var line2=[['2008-06-30 8:00AM',4], ['2008-06-30 9:00AM',6.5], ['2008-06-30 10:00AM',5.7], ['2008-06-30 11:00AM',9], ['2008-06-30 12:00PM',8.2]];

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to plot a Date axis with version: 1.0.4 Revision: 1121 and could not get it to plot the graph when I had hours as a time unit for plotting the points (all my points were plotting at the very end of the X axis)
Workaround for me was comment out this line -

`min = min.getTime() + min.getUtcOffset();`

from jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.js

Not sure if this is a bug but the plot did work for me after this code change.

Comment: I may have over thought this way too much. It's a much simpler problem than I was trying to make it.

I ended up using .CanvasAxisTickRenderer and my dates as text. I didn't need date/time functionality so I'll just chart it and move on. Thank you for your help!